# share button in android app is not working when showAsAction is always or ifroom

Tags: android, android-actionbar, share

I am working on an android webview app, i have added share action on action bar which works fine when showAsAction is 'never, but stop working as soon as i change it to 'always' or 'ifRoom'`
my code is:

```
 private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
 }

 @Override
 public final boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.menu_item_share:
            shareURL();
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 private void shareURL() {
     Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
     shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView.getUrl());
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This!"));
 }
```

if someone could help, thank you.

Comment: post your menu.xml

Comment: have you added namespace prefix to use `showAsAction `?

Comment: post your `menu_main.xml` code

Comment: <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

Comment: maybe you should remove the `actionProviderClass`

Comment: hey, thanx man, it's working, but now instead of icon it's showing share text on action bar. but thats fine with me, thank you once again.

Comment: are you using appcompat library?

Comment: thats because you didn't add the `android:icon` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"` and add the `android:icon="@drawable/image-name"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you actually have space to display it?

You could try disabling the title to see is that created enough room:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**Update:**

Can you try using:

```
public void setOnMenuItemClickListener (Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener listener)
```

I believe the toolbar has a separate listener than the dropdown menu.

The code could look something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);

tb.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
tb.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {


// Menu item should be returned here (the one you tap on the toolbar)

        return false;
    }
});

}
```

Comment: i can see icon on the action bar when it's always or ifRoom, but it's not clickable. but works fine when showAsAction is 'never'.